# Find total amount of data moved through SSIS

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, ssis

Is there a way in SSIS (through custom code is fine as well) to find out the amount of data that has moved from a source to a destination?
When I say the amount of data, I mean in Bytes, Kb's, Mb's etc? I was thinking of writing a code in .net but I dont have a good starting point. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks for any suggestions or tips.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a great answer, but perhaps you can find something in existing tools.

If you can isolate to a certain server or logical disk you can use performance monitor to gather statistics.  See [this whitepaper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537533%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

SQL profiler also has a 'writes' column, but I'm not sure if this can be translated to MB.

You could also inspect free space in a database before and after the load.